# Spring 4.0 EL cron expression doesn't get resolve from @Bean method

Tags: spring, cron, spring-el

As per requirement, I need to get cron expression from DB and set it to
Scheduled annotation's param but getting Invalid Cron expression error. Below is
my code and it works only when I add cron expression directly in `@Scheduled` param

```
@Component
@EnableScheduling
@Configuration
public class TicketReportScheduler
{

   private static Log _log = 
   LogFactoryUtil.getLog(TicketReportScheduler.class);
   @Autowired
   NotificationUtility notificationUtility;

   @Bean
   public String getConfigRefreshValue() {
      return "0 */1 * * * ?";
   }    

   //@Scheduled(cron = "0 */1 * * * ?") -  works
   @Scheduled(cron = "#{@getConfigRefreshValue}") // error 
   public void demoServiceMethod() throws Exception {
      _log.info("Cron job started " + new Date());
  }
}
```

**Error while run:**

I googled a lot but unable to fix my problem. As per requirement, I have to pass cron expression from DB. For POC, I created a simple method and return cron expression but it doesn't work and I am getting below error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Encountered invalid @Scheduled method 'demoServiceMethod': Cron expression must consist of 6 fields (found 1 in "#{@getConfigRefreshValue}")
```

Comment: You can use a value expression i.e. `${}` not a SpEL expression for resolving values.

Comment: same problem:Encountered invalid @Scheduled method 'demoServiceMethod': Cron expression must consist of 6 fields (found 1 in "${getConfigRefreshValue}")

Comment: Ofcourse that won't work as when using a value expression it has to be a property in the environment. It cannot be a bean.

Comment: I understand your point but I need this one from DB not from a property file. There must be some way.

Comment: Where the property comes from doesn't matter. Property doesn't automatically mean property file.

Comment: So you mean, I need property and set its value from DB and use this in Cron expression. I will try this approach and if it works, will share my result

Comment: You can add a database driver `PropertySource`. You can also ditch the `@Scheduled` and use the `TaskScheduler` to schedule your own tasks based on the expression from the database, the latter is easier to achieve.,